# Node.Js Through2- modifying stream

Tags: node.js, stream, node.js-stream

I am experimenting with Node.js streams using `through2`. I have a stream that is a index.html file and I am trying to modify the index.html contents line by line with adding a `-------` on every line. I have:

```
  indexHTML
      .pipe(through2.obj(function(obj, enc, next) {
        blah = obj.contents.toString().split('\n');
        blah.forEach(function(element) {
            this.push("-------");
            this.push(element):
        });
        next();
      })).pipe(process.stdout);
```

The issue I am having at the moment `this.push()` is not available inside the `blah.forEach()` array method. Any suggestions on how I can achieve modifying the index.html stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the `forEach()` instead of a regular for-loop, `forEach()` accepts a [second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters) which is the desired `this` context:

```
blah.forEach(function(element) {
  this.push("-------");
  this.push(element):
}, this);
```

You can also always use the more general "self" workaround:

```
var self = this;
blah.forEach(function(element) {
  self.push("-------");
  self.push(element):
});
```